# PHP persistent variable type without the need of validation

Tags: php, lua

I had this question in my mind for some time. Say we have a variable:
`$foo = $_GET['value'];` (this is a generical example)

I wanted to know if PHP has something similar to Lua where you can have something like:

```
local randomvar = "string";
local foo = randomvar or 0;
```

This way, `foo` would be considered integer and if `randomvar` is not an integer, the value `0` will be assigned to it.

Comment: Your understanding of Lua is incorrect (`print(type( "orange" or 0)) --string`) but fortunately that didn't prevent you from getting what you asked for in PHP.

Comment: @TomBlodget I'm not programming in standard Lua, the code I wrote works where I'm using it. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is method `is_numeric`

```
  <?
      $foo = "S"; 
      $bar = (is_numeric($foo)) ? $foo:0;
      echo $bar;
  ?>
```

Please consider going through docs for your purpose http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: Hah, I never actually considered trying that.

Comment: $foo = "String";
$bar = is_int($foo) || 0;
print_r($bar);
<<< Won't work at all

Comment: I have made a edit on the code. Please check if this supports your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it's type:

```
$foo = (int) $_GET['value'];
```

That wouldn't set it to 0. but it would definitely remove non-numeric characters.

Or you can use is_int():

```
function stringToZero($var) {
    return (is_int($_GET['value'])) ? $var : 0;
}

$temp = $_GET['value']; // because I'm not sure it's correct to send a $_GET to a function. might not be necessary.
$randomvar = stringToZero($temp);
unset($temp);
```

Comment: I was already using (int), yet I found the Lua approach more flexible for my purpose, as (int) on a string would return 0, what if I want 127 f.e.

Comment: You could change it to: function stringToZero($var,$int=0) {
    return (is_int($_GET['value'])) ? $var : $int;
}    then you could call $randomvar = stringToZero($temp,127);